# PHHueSDK lists disconnected bridge when searching for the available bridges for Android

Tags: android, philips-hue

I am working with two Philips Hue bridges with my app. It's all good when both the bridges are UP and running but when I remove one of the bridge by removing the power source, my app still lists both the bridges on doing the bridge search again. I search for the bridge as mentioned in the official documentation:

```
public void doBridgeSearch() {
    PHBridgeSearchManager sm = (PHBridgeSearchManager)
            phHueSDK.getSDKService(PHHueSDK.SEARCH_BRIDGE);
    // Start the UPNP Searching of local bridges.
    sm.search(true, true);
}
```

and the listener

```
     private PHSDKListener listener = new PHSDKListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCacheUpdated(List<Integer> list, PHBridge phBridge) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onCacheUpdated");

        }

        @Override
        public void onBridgeConnected(PHBridge phBridge, String username) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onBridgeConnected "+username);

        }

        @Override
        public void onAuthenticationRequired(PHAccessPoint phAccessPoint) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onAuthenticationRequired");
            phHueSDK.startPushlinkAuthentication(phAccessPoint);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAccessPointsFound(List<PHAccessPoint> list) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onAccessPointsFound");
            if(list != null && list.size() > 0) {
                phHueSDK.getAccessPointsFound().clear();
                phHueSDK.getAccessPointsFound().addAll(list);
                Log.d(TAG, "no of bridge available "+list.size());
                connect(phHueSDK.getAccessPointsFound().get(0));
            }
        }
    }
```

In the call back onAccessPointsFound() the list size is 2 even when only one bridge is running. How to get only the available bridges at that time?

Comment: Same thing happens with me. This doesn't seem to be an SDK issue as it reproduces even when you clear cache on device. My prime suspect is that it has to do something with router cache.